# Using react-spring in a TypeScript component class throwing compilation problems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-spring

I am trying to use a swipeable button in my component similar to [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2455jj0wwp) I was able to make it work with React but TypeScript is giving me problems. Please see the compilation errors below:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { withGesture } from 'react-with-gesture'
import { Spring, animated } from 'react-spring'

interface Props {
  name: string
  sex: string
  age: string
  xDelta?: number
  down?: boolean
}

@withGesture
export class Person extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    const { xDelta, down, children } = this.props
    let x = 0
    return (
      <Spring native to={{ x: down ? xDelta : 0 }} immediate={name => down && name === 'x'}>
        {({ x }) => (
          <div className="item" style={{ backgroundColor: xDelta < 0 ? '#FF1C68' : '#14D790' }}>
            <animated.div className="fg" style={{ transform: x.interpolate(x => `translate3d(${x}px,0,0)`) }}>
              {down && Math.abs(xDelta) > 50 ? (xDelta < 0 ? 'Cancel' : 'Accept') : children}
            </animated.div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Spring>
    )
  }
}

export default Person
```

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Person.tsx:19:62
>           TS2322: Type '(name: string) => boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean | string[] | ((key: string) => boolean) | (false & ((name: string) => boolean | undefined)) | (true & ((name: string) => boolean | undefined)) | (string[] & ((name: string) => boolean | undefined)) | (((key: string) => boolean) & ((name: string) => boolean | undefined)) | undefined'.
>         Type '(name: string) => boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type '(key: string) => boolean'.
>           Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>             Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Person.tsx:21:59
>           TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Person.tsx:23:33
>           TS2345: Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Person.tsx:23:49
>           TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
>       ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Is this something to do with my tsconfig settings? I have been trying last 10 hours to be able to run react-spring with a gesture example using Typescript and my own config files. I would appreciate directions.

Thanks.

Comment: could you please provide an example of working with this library with Typescript?

Like, I want to use this in my render function:

<Spring
  from={{ opacity: 0 }}
  to={{ opacity: 1 }}>
  {props => <div style={props}>hello</div>}
</Spring> 
It causes me typescript type errors and I don't know how to solve it :( Apperently you have found an approach, could you reveal it?

The official documentation about TS support is very poor.

Comment: Can you ask the question as a new question, I am not entirely sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `xDelta` and `down` props are optional, they will be `undefined` if they weren't passed in.  I assume you have the `strictNullChecks` compiler option (or the `strict` option, which includes it) enabled, so TypeScript is checking that you deal with `undefined` properly.  In this case, the easiest solution is probably to take advantage of the `defaultProps` support by making the `xDelta` and `down` props non-optional from the perspective of the component implementation (remove the `?` marks in `Props`) and adding the following in class `Person` (substitute the default values you actually want):

```
  static defaultProps = {
    down: false,
    xDelta: 0
  };
```

After I make this change, I'm left with one `noImplicitAny` error on the `x` parameter in `` x => `translate3d(${x}px,0,0)` ``.  To resolve that error, specify the correct type for `x`: I'm guessing it's `number` or `string`.